# How to reproduce programatically the click at "update button" of Order in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I need programatically reproduce the event of click the update button of an order. I don't want to select any "order action". The order is already created and I can get the order ID. Please see picture.
I only need to trigger programatically that event. What function can I use or how could I do it? Manty thanks  [image]